# Match consecutive duplicate characters, ignoring case

Tags: python, regex

So I know `(.)\1` is the format for finding consecutive characters with a regular expression, but I've noticed it is case sensitive, so it won't pick up `"sS"` or `"hH"` on a text field or string.

How would I change this, and also how would I implement it using python 3.5 with the `re.findall` method?

Comment: I think you mean it **is** case-sensitive and you don't want it to be? Or what do you mean?

Comment: I've been stupid. I don't want it to be case sensitive, I want it to match two letters in a string that are consecutive if that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
re.findall(r'(.)\1', 'aA', re.IGNORECASE)
```

to match strings like `aA`.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE

Comment: thanks, does this work with integers as well still? can i still find them using the regex

Comment: Damn :D You wrote the same as me and i accidentally edited yours

Comment: I don't know if this is me being stupid or not, but the 'r' beforehand is highlighted green just as the regex itself, should it be doing this?

Comment: @rerpha the `r` before the regex is to indicate it as a raw string it has nothing to do with the regex .The regex is the part after the `r"This is regex"`

Answer (score 1):

You should ignore the case like this:

```
re.IGNORECASE
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html